# Why ScrollViewer in WPF can't edit a copy template?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I want to create a template for ScrollViewer, but the `Edit a Copy...` item in context menu was unavailable.

[image: The Edit a Copy... was unavailable]

But the same item for ScrollBar was available.

[image: The Edit a Copy... was available]

Why this function can't use for some controls? And if it's unavailable, how can I get the template xaml code for those contols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing, 2022 may not support this operation for the time being, you can go to [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=8) to make a request.

Environment:2019 16.11.7

[image]

[image]

Below is the template.

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp3.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp3"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ScrollViewerControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
            <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Rectangle x:Name="Corner" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" CanHorizontallyScroll="False" CanVerticallyScroll="False" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="0"/>
                <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VerticalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Minimum="0" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"/>
                <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="HorizontalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="0" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Minimum="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I'm going to give feedback on the issue.